# Import postgresql database dump

Tags: php, postgresql, dump

I have the following work flow which I'd like to automate with short PHP script.

1. Download gzfile (with db dump) from specific URL (potentially FTP).
2. Decode the file to txt.
3. Import the txt to local postgre with psql (using cmd).

Now I have 2 questions:

- What is the best way to pass the gunzipped file to pg_query?
- I get an error when PHP reaches this line:
  `COPY rf (datum, id_emailu_op, recency, frequency) FROM stdin;
  2011-08-29  8484    3   1`. Can the *stdin* be a problem?

Thank you all!

Comment: `gzcat dump.gz|psql` at a shell prompt would decompress the .gz file and sent the output directly to postgres.

Comment: A short Bash script is probably simpler, depending on what your needs are.

Comment: I would recommend dumping using `pg_dump -Fc` and restore using `pg_restore`.

Answer (score 2):

A pg_dump file is meant to be imported via psql. You can load the file contents in, and even decompress it with php, then open a pipe to psql writing data out to that process (assuming you are on a unix machine). When psql is executed in this way as far as it's concerned the data you're writing via your php script is coming in via stdin.